# strange behaviour with a tableviewcontroller

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

[iphone http://sharingdream.com/phone.jpg](http://sharingdream.com/phone.jpg)

Dear all, 
I'm having a strange problem with an application I'm building using mono touch.
Basically like you can see from the image, there is a grid on the first image. The class
is called DialogViewController and extends a UITableViewController. This one is working perfectly. If I click on a cell than I have the second image (the one in the middle). So far everything is ok. If I'm on the second view (the image on the middle) and I click on the first icon (the little blu ball) than I have what you can see on the third image.
This image should be exactly the same of the first image, but for a strange reason I'm losing all the content from this view. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you using a NavigationController within your first tab?  Without seeing any code, it's difficult to say what the problem is.

Comment: Hi Jason here you can see the code: [link](http://sharingdream.com/code.txt). The MainWindow.xib has a tab bat controller and on the first tab there the class you see on the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by setting each tabbaritem to have `enabled=false` when selected.